# Use all types defined inside a class

Tags: c++

I have a struct X defined, which defines some types inside of it:

```cpp
struct X {
    using A = int;
    using B = double;
    // ...
};
```

Now, it is possible to use these types outside of the class using `typename`, e.g.:

```cpp
typename X::A a = 3;
typename X::B b = 3.5;
```

**My question:** If `X` was a namespace, then it would have been possible to use `using namespace X` to avoid typing `typename X::...` all of the time, but since `X` is a class, then we cannot do that. Is there any way to use the namespace `X` in order to avoid typing `typename X::...` all of the time?

Doing something like `using namespace X` does not seem to work. It *is* possible to use a singular type, using something like `using A = X::A` however I want a way to do this automatically for all types defined within a class.

Note that `X` may be a templated class, if that matters.

Comment: Notice that `typename` is superfluous here: `X::A a = 3;` would be good.

Comment: True; In my project I have something along the lines of `using type = typename A<T>::type`, in which `typename` is necessary.

Comment: If `X` is an empty type, you can inherit from `X` to inherit its types. This is a common trick for traits types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are designed for that purpose and gives more possibilities than classes in that respect.

But **no**, there is no such thing as `using classspace X; A a = 3;` (or equivalent) for class-name scope.

Considering that `using namespace ...` is often considered a bad practice, I doubt it will come soon.

Comment: Shame. Could be useful, as it is quite good practice to define a lot of types internally for a class.

Comment: You can, but you have to use the `X::A` syntax. Or even `using A = X::A;` in the scope where it matters.